# How to add a domain name to an existing WCF REST web service?

Tags: rest, wcf, web-hosting

I have an existing WCF REST service running on an Azure Windows Server 2012 using IIS8. Let say 1x.2x.3x.4x:7777/InvService.svc/RESTquery is how my users currently use the service.

I am wanting to replace the IP address with a hostname, say www.testDomain.com so the user will can then use www.testDomain.com:7777/InvService.svc/RESTquery.

After obtaining the domain name from GoDaddy, assigning IP 1x.2x.3x.4x, and testing it (my default site on the server comes up, hence why I am using port 7777). When I try www.testDomain.com:7777/InvService.svc/RESTquery I get a "Connection Timed Out" error.

I believe I am needing to add or change something inside my Web.config file but cannot seem to find the right answer. Here is what my current unsuccessful Web.config file looks like.

```
<services>
  <service name="WCFInventoryService.InvService">
    <endpoint address="RESTquery" behaviorConfiguration="restPoxBehavior"
      binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WCFInventoryService.IInvService" />
      <identity>
            <dns value="www.testDomain.com" />
        </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <host>
        <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://www.testDomain.com/"/>
        </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
```

What am I doing wrong? or should try?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. The problem was how the domain was set up in GoDaddy. In the GoDaddy account, the domain was set up to forward to the IP address and not to point to. Once I removed the forwarding record and changed the A record to point to the IP address in the GoDaddy account, the WCF service was accessible by using www.testDomain.com:7777/InvService.svc/RESTquery